# Adding an attribute to a Controller form at @GetMapping using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Validating the overlapping of date intervals, in the implementation of the Validator class. I get a list from a Posgresql database, which I would like to show, next to the error message.

I've tried to insert it, without succeeding, with this line of code:

```
model.addAttribute("dateOverlaps", pricesValidator.getDBIntervals());
```

That's the complete code:

```
@Controller 
public class PricesController {

@Autowired
private RateRepository rateRepository;

@Autowired
private PricesValidator pricesValidator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(pricesValidator);
}


//Enter new price form
@GetMapping("/admin/rates/priceform")
public String priceForm(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("rate", new Rate());
    model.addAttribute("dateOverlaps", pricesValidator.getDBIntervals());

    return "/admin/rates/priceform";
}

@PostMapping("/admin/rates/priceform")
public String priceSubmit(@ModelAttribute @Valid Rate price, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

        return "/admin/rates/priceform";
    }
    rateRepository.addRate(price);

    return "redirect:/admin/rates/prices";
}

}
```

I use Thymeleaf, but I take for granted that the problem is not with the viewer.

This is the html view:

```
 <!--Global validation results-->
 <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">
     <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" 
          th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('global')}"> 
          <div th:switch="${err}">
          <p th:case="error.fromAfterTo" th:text="#error.fromAfterTo}"></p>
          <p th:case="error.overlaps" th:text="#{error.overlaps}"></p>
            <ul>
               <li th:text="#{from} + ' - ' + #{to}"></li>
               <li th:each="interval : ${dateOverlaps}"
                   th:text="${#temporals.format(interval.datefrom, 'dd/MM/yyyy')} + '-' + 
                   ${#temporals.format(interval.dateto, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}">Intervals</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
 </div><!--Global validation results-->
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you try to get the value in the view?

Comment: So what do you get exactly when you call the endpoint?

Comment: I have added the view. @DanielOlszewski

Comment: I get the error message with the #{error.overlaps} text, but without a sign of the intervals list. The validator works. @zakariaamine

Comment: What are you doing, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Have you debugged your code? Printed what pricesValidator.getDBIntervals() returns. Looks at the generated HTML? I don't know anything about thymeleaf, but the ul is inside a switch, but not inside any case. is it normal? Is the first li being displayed?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, doing some more research, I've focused the problem, with a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that pricesValidator.getDBIntervals() at @GetMapping:

```
model.addAttribute("dateOverlaps", pricesValidator.getDBIntervals());
```

is calling the list that I want to show with the message error, which is empty until the form has been submitted. Because its values, are picked up from the database, with the validation process.

That raises a new question:

**How can I set this model attribute in the @PostMapping section?**

The answer to this question is simple, in the @PostMapping section, you can set a Model, as well as in the @GetMapping one. In my case, this was the solution:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/rates/priceform")
public String priceSubmit(@ModelAttribute @Valid Rate price, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("dateOverlaps", pricesValidator.getDBIntervals());
        return "/admin/rates/priceform";
    }
    rateRepository.addRate(price);

    return "redirect:/admin/rates/prices";
}
```